# Calculating sum of a column from web service

Tags: c#

Let me start out by saying I know nothing of C#. I do web design, and am pretty much limited to that with a limited amount of javascript.

I was given a web service, and the goal is to pull the data with that, which I was able to do. Now I'm trying to figure out a way to calculate the total of one of the columns. Everything I've seen has talked about DataTables, which I know nothing of. I'm not sure if DataTables are a required thing, or anything really.

The question is - is there a way to calculate the total of one of the columns? The column is called "total" and I'd like to get the total into a string called "points".

edit - 
I'm not the one who made the web service, nor do I have access to editing it. I emailed the guy who made it a few hours ago telling him exactly what was going on, no response. Unfortunately, there's not a whole lot more information I can add.

```
decimal total = Convert.ToDecimal(t11) + Convert.ToDecimal(t12);
```

That's the code to add t11 and t12 together, which gets the total, but I need to figure out a way to add up the total for each row.

edit2 -

```
 decimal GetTotal()
{
    decimal total = 0;
    foreach (XmlNode rec in records)
    {
        total += Convert.ToDecimal(rec.SelectSingleNode("sub_total").innerText);
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: We need to see the code!

Comment: Surely do. And some info on what the webservice is capable of. Doing this with the web service will be much simpler than with javascript. Let the server code do it's job or processing that information

Comment: need more information

Comment: and welcome to stack overflow, by the way. Hope you aren't feeling too beat up.. 0.0

Comment: If the collection is an `IEnumerable<T>` and the "column" is a numeric type then you can just use `.Sum()` on a selection of that "column".  Basically, it's not only possible but likely trivial.  However, it all depends on the objects and types involved.

Answer (score 1):

Without any more information, this is the best I can do to get you started.

Using a WebMethod on a page or web service:

```
using System.Linq;

[WebMethod]
public static int GetSum()
{
    int nSum = 0;

    // get a reference to the column...
    nSum = columnRef.Sum();

    // or get a reference to the table
    nSum = tableRef.Sum(o => o.oneOfTheColumns);

    // if the values in the column are strings representing numbers.
    nSum = tableRef.Sum(o => int.Parse(o.oneOfTheCollumns)); 

    // follow the same pattern for other number types

    return nSum;
}
```

Comment: Your function is missing a return type, and a class, and your using statement is off. This doesn't seem very helpful other than providing the correct LINQ queries.

Comment: It isn't a full working copy and paste kind of solution. This is a guide and example of the pieces needed to solve the issue. I do need to correct some of the obvious issues, though. Thanks for letting me know about the issues.

Comment: +1 Thats certainly much better. Note to users, this still needs to be in a class somewhere, but if you don't know how to do that, you should probably be reading a C# book, not SO.

Comment: @brett He says he doesn't want to make any more changes to the WS, and told me something like this is what I want -

Comment: @user3869708 You will either need to update the webservice to include a method like this or create a webmethod outside of the webservice that can still access the data. There really isn't any way around those two methods of applying the solution that I know of.

Comment: @brett Do you know of any good tutorial for something like that? Most everything that I've found just show bits and pieces.

Comment: Well.. the existing code in your project should give you a pretty good setup for adjusting the webservice yourself if you can, and webmethod tutorials are plentiful. [Here is one of many that can be found using your favorite search engine..](http://deebujacob.blogspot.com/2012/01/aspnet-ajax-web-method-call-using.html)